# Как уменьшить объём потребляемой оперативной памяти?

Tags: c#, ado.net

**Используется**
C#
MySql

При добавлении в таблицу MySql новых записей растёт потребление оперативной памяти.

**Код**

```
            #region *** ЗАПРОС ***
        tbl_name = textBox115.Text; // Имя редактируемой таблицы. Пирсваиваем значение переменной
        sql_zpr_01 = "SELECT * FROM " + tbl_name; // Строка запроса
        #endregion *** ЗАПРОС ***

        sqlCom_0 = new MySqlCommand(sql_zpr_01, connMySql_db_2);
        sqlCom_0.ExecuteNonQuery();            
        MySqlDtAdp_0 = new MySqlDataAdapter(sqlCom_0);

        #region *** СОЗДАНИЕ ДТ ***
        dt_025 = new DataTable();            

        MySqlDtAdp_0.Fill(dt_025); // -> DataTable            
        #endregion *** СОЗДАНИЕ ДТ ***

        MySqlCommandBuilder commandBuilder = new MySqlCommandBuilder(MySqlDtAdp_0);


        int str; // кол. строк в пакете

        str = Convert.ToInt32(textBox123.Text); // кол. строк 
            for (int s = 1; s <= str; s++)
            {
                name_str = textBox116.Text + "_" + s;
                zpch_str = textBox117.Text + "_" + s;                

                newRow = dt_025.NewRow();
                newRow["name"] = name_str;
                newRow["zpch"] = zpch_str;
                dt_025.Rows.Add(newRow);
            }
            MySqlDtAdp_0.Update(dt_025);
```

**Вопрос**
Как уменьшить объём потребляемой оперативной памяти?

**Дополню:** при добавлении записей с использованием `MySqlParameter` увеличение потребления оперативной памяти не происходит.

Comment: Про параметризованные запросы не слышал?

Comment: @Alex78191 Вы имеете ввиду такой?  см. ссылку -
 codeshare.io/5RBNPQ . Т.е. для данных ситуаций желательно использовать такой код?

Comment: Я не люблю когда используют запросы, подверженные внедрению SQL-кода.

Comment: @Alex78191 Вы бы не могли подсказать как лучше сделать?

Comment: Я и так сказал.

Comment: @Alex7819 Не могли бы вы показать пример(на примере моего или прислать ссылку аналога) такого кода. PS. Прошу прощения, я пока только осваиваю, поэтому столько вопросов.

Comment: параметризованные вопросы вы правильно сделали в примере.

Comment: @Alex78191 Вы про этот пример? см. ссылку - codeshare.io/5RBNPQ

Comment: да я про этот пример

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как я вижу, твой `DataTable` не глобальный=> при выходе из контекста его должен поглотить сборщик мусора и очистить ОЗУ. Однако, неизвестно когда это произойдет, так как он активируется только в подходящий для этого момента, например ОЗУ заканчивается или программа вошла в некритичный участок. Даже если ты вызовешь `Dispose`, то сборщик мусора моментально не убьет объект.

При добавлении строк ручками-запросом прирост минимальный за счет того, что не создается здоровенный объект-`DataTable`, который включает в себя большое семейство объектов+трекинг изменений, который позволяет хранить 3(Вроде) состояния записи.

Иными словами, если затраты озу- это критично для вас, то лучше отказаться от использования `DataTable` и вставлять данные через параметризированные запросы.

То, что в запросе с параметром нету прироста ОЗУ объясняется тем, что вы передаете переменные значимого типа=> они хранятся в стеке, а не в куче и уничтожаются моментально без сборщика мусора.

И вообще, вы не правильно трактуете предназначение `DataTable`. Он больше нужен для визуализации небольшого кол-ва данных и простого обновления их на сервере. Если в него пихать слишком много, то неудивительно, что он разбухнет.

P.S Меня поправили в комментах. Проблема у вас в том, что вы действительно делаете лишний Fill. Т.е вы наполняете таблицу всеми данными из таблицы бд.

Comment: Так а что использовать?

Comment: А ORM как будет?

Comment: @Alex78191, большие ORM строятся все равно на Ado.net. Например, EF тоже жрет много. Можно использовать ORM, которые близки к SQL-Dapper и Linq2Db.

Comment: Да не в памяти у него проблема, он лишний Fill делает

Comment: @PavelMayorov, да, действительно не заметил.

Comment: Переменные значимого типа совсем необязательно хранятся в стеке, `MySqlParameter` получает значение как объект типа object, значит произойдёт упаковка, ну и сам `MySqlParameter` тоже надо создать. Так что стек тут ни при чём.

Comment: @iluxa1810 **1.** `твой DataTable ` - я "плаваю" в терминах. Немножко доработал код показал `DataTable`  
и BindingSource в начале, что я как я думаю является показателем, что DataTable глобальный (могу ошибаться. Начинающий). 
Новый код - https://codeshare.io/G8JRbB

Comment: @iluxa1810 **2.** `создается здоровенный объект-DataTable` - добавил в код ещё один цикл `for`, что позволит разбить добавление строк на "пакеты". Т.е. добавил 1 000 строк, очистил `DataTable`.
НО! к сожеление это не привело к результату, ОЗУ всё равно растёт. #ВОПРОС_1#: можно ли решить проблему по средствам способа предложенного мной в данном пункте? Может идея правильная, а я неправильно делаю?

Comment: @iluxa1810 **3.** `если затраты озу- это критично для вас` - хотелось бы... Пример: использую я это "дело" в парсере, который работает на автомате. Он качает информацию, заносит в MySql, и "сжирает" всю оперативку. **4.** `вы не правильно трактуете предназначение DataTable` - я только осваиваю эти вопросы, поэтому прошу делать поправку на нелогичность решений. Мне показалось, что использование `MySqlCommandBuilder` как-то компактнее чем `MySqlParameter`. Хотя могу ошибаться. #ВОПРОС_2#: Хотелось бы услышать ваше мнение: что компактнее: использование `MySqlCommandBuilder` или `MySqlParameter`?

Comment: @iluxa1810 **5.** `вы действительно делаете лишний Fill.` - Не понимаю... 
5.1 Таблица на MySql `пуста` 
5.2 Выполнили `Fill`
5.3 Циклом наполняем `DataTable` строкой `dt_025.Rows.Add(newRow);` 
5.4 Обновляем таблицу MySql `MySqlDtAdp_0.Update(dt_025)` 
5.5 Чистим `DataTable` - `dt_025.Clear();` (см. новый код)
 #ВОПРОС_3#: не могли бы вы скорректировать код без лишнего `Fill`. Я просто не совсем понимаю как связан с  ростом потребления ОЗУ

Comment: @iluxa1810 **6.** #ВОПРОС_4#: Правильно ли я понимаю, что альтернатива использованию `MySqlCommandBuilder` это `MySqlParameter`?
 Правильно ли я понимаю, что данное решение с `MySqlParameter` должно выглядеть так https://codeshare.io/5RBNPQ ? 
 Или можно как-то сделать проще и правильней?